# MySQL Stored Procedure Insert Loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Trying to search for an answer to no avail. I am trying to do insert a value into a table, then populate a many to many relationship table.
I am calling this from python and I could do multiple calls to mysql, but I'd like to execute this once.
Here is the relationship: 
address --> device_address_mappings <-- device 
Below is an example of what I'd like to do but in Python. I'd like this to be a stored procedure on the DB though.

```
addressID=10
for device in devices:
    ** Runs a query like - INSERT INTO device_address_mappings addressID, deviceID VALUES (addressID, device['deviceID']);
```

Comment: Should every device be linked to every address? If not, what's the logic to associate them?

Comment: Yes, there is another value associated with it that defines its current status (deployed, not deployed yet). The db much more than this, just limiting what info I put online.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Could you perhaps share some data and the result you'd want to get for it?

Comment: I am deploying addresses to devices and need to know if the device got it, so when I create a new address it needs to go to all devices. At any one time it might be on some devices but not all, so I need to many to many relationship with a stored ‘deploy’ value.